# Google Chrome Out of Memory When nothing else is running

Tags: google-chrome, memory, browser, memory-leaks

I'm having an issue where Google Chrome will only display the "He's dead, Jim" error (out of memory). I can't even go to the settings tab without it showing the error. Nothing else is running, only the one tab, all other programs (aside from antivirus) are closed.

I've tried reinstalling Chrome (and removing the old registry entries), and I've cut everything else running on the system down to the bare minimum. Task manager shows that there's still tons of memory free.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: why are all the comments gone?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Good question, I have no idea. It's too bad they don't stay up, it could be a useful resource to someone else later on with the same issue.

Comment: Is it fixed when you use the 64Bit Version of Chrome?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes it was. Although I did do a bunch of other stuff along with it so it's hard to say if that was all that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You have over 3GB of free virtual RAM with a largest piece of 2GB. Here you shouldn't get `Out of Memory` errors. To workaround this, you should use the [64Bit Version of Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/index.html).